# Get supported type from Spring Data repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a list of repository beans existing in my Spring Boot application and I need to link each `CrudRepository` into corresponding entity class so I end with a `Map<Class, CrudRepository>` object.

Example repository:

```
public interface ReviewRepository extends CrudRepository<Review, ReviewId>
```

And I need help with the following method linking repository with a proper entity class:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    final Map<Class, CrudRepository> repositoryMap;

    public MyService(List<Class> entityClasses, List<CrudRepository> existingRepositories) {
        this.repositoryMap = logicGoesHere(entityClasses, existingRepositories); // <== HERE
    }
```

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. What concrete problem are you trying to solve with this strategy?

Comment: We are trying to introduce something like a rich-domain-objects with entities with auto-injected corresponding repositories. And to inject proper repository into entity, I need to find a correct one from the list of available ones.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Might be the `[0]` should be replaced by actual lookup (in my case just by accident zero was a correct index)

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl;
import sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository;

import static java.util.function.Function.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

@Configuration
class Config  {

    @Bean
    public Map<Class, JpaRepository> classToRepo( List<JpaRepository> repos) {
        return repos.stream().collect(toMap(this::extractEntityClass, identity()));
    }

    private Class extractEntityClass(JpaRepository repository) {
        try {
            Method getGenericInfo = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("getGenericInfo");

            getGenericInfo.setAccessible(true);

            ClassRepository cr = (ClassRepository) getGenericInfo.invoke(repository.getClass().getInterfaces()[0]);
            Type t = ((ParameterizedTypeImpl) cr.getSuperInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            return (Class) t;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And you can inject it using `@Qualifier("classToRepo")`